# How to create Event handler in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, events, autoeventwireup

In my `Global.asax` generated file I couldn't find `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` Event. How can I create it so that c# will Bind it automatically?

Comment: Just add it to the `Global.asax` file - `protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { .... }`

Comment: Will it be fired? Like isnt it required to generate like we do for Page events in asp.net. Like `Page.Load += ...`

Comment: Yes it will be fired. Just add your code and it will be fired for each request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method for PostAuthenticateRequest in the MVC page life cycle.
You just need to add it in your global.asax implementation as it is not a standart method that every application needs. You can refer to the following article and include the method on your own: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.visualstudioservicesapplication.application_postauthenticaterequest(v=vs.120).aspx